# Beginner VHDL doubt

Tags: vhdl

```
 constant <clock>_period : time := 10 ns;
```

What is the error with this code ? it says syntax error near "<".

Comment: Using google I'd say: constant clk_period : time := 10 ns; would be correct

Comment: Why do you have the “<“ and “>”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you generated a testbench-template in Vivado or ISE, as these programs generate code like this.

The idea is that you replace the `<clock>` with the name of your clock-signal: If your clock-signal is called `clk`, the line would become

```
 constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;
```

which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

VHDL names can contain the following:

- letters
- numbers
- underscores

They are also case insensitive, have to start with a letter and cannot contain two adjacent underscores (From the Doulos Golden Reference Guide).

< and > are not a letter, number or an underscore.

Comment: Names are a larger subject, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names. You're describing a basic identifier, a lexical element  see 15.4.2. There's also the extended identifier (15.4.3). `extended_identifier ::= \ graphic_character { graphic_character } \ ` where a backslash can be represented in the sequence of graphic characters by escaping it with a preceding backslash. `constant \<clock>_period\ : time := 10 ns;` would be a legal declaration with the object name `\<clock>_period\ `.